# Recuperar id de una imagen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, imagen

Estoy intentando recuperar la id de esta imagen pero no consigo recuperarla como lo puedo hacer?

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="datosFoto">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
    <th scope="col">Fecha de Subida</th>
    <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
    <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php 
     $contador = 0 ;
  foreach ($data["Fotos"] as $p) :  
    $contador ++;
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?= $p["Nombre"] ?></td>
      <td><?= $p["FechaSubida"] ?></td>
      <td><img id="imagen_<?= $contador?>" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($p['imagen']) ?>" alt="<?php echo $p['Nombre']; ?>"></td>
      <td>
        <input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $p['idFoto'] ?>" name="id" id="id">
        <button class="btn btn-success update" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateFoto" >
          <ion-icon class="lead" name="create-outline"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
          <ion-icon class="lead" name="trash-outline"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>

  <?php require_once("modificarFoto.php") ?>
</tbody>
```

**mi codigo AJAX donde recogo los valores de esa fila y me lo muestra en el modal**

```
jQuery('.update').on('click', function () {
//consigue los elementos de la tabla de fotos
$tr = $(this).closest('tr');
//mapea los datos y los guarda en la viariable datos
var datos = $tr.children("td").map(function () {
   
    return $(this).text();
});
console.log(datos)

$('#nom').val(datos[0]);
$('#date').val(datos[1]);
console.log($('#imagen_').attr("id")) 
});
```

con ese console.log estoy intentando recuperar la id única en concreto de esa imagen pero solo me sale la palabra imagen me gustaría saber como coger la id completa

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo lo siguiente dentro de tu codigo modificarlo de tal manera que quede asi, y prueba si da.

1. En mi caso coloco una clase imagen para capturarla mas simple.
2. pongo lo que tienes en id en otro atributo.
3. con un split puedo capturar solo el id

```js
$( ".imagenes" ).each(function() {
  //console.log($( this ).attr("data-id").split('_')[0]);
  console.log($( this ).attr("data-id").split('_')[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="imagenes" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($p['imagen']) ?>" data-id='imagen_1' alt="<?php echo $p['Nombre']; ?>">

<img class="imagenes" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($p['imagen']) ?>" data-id='imagen_2' alt="<?php echo $p['Nombre']; ?>">

<img class="imagenes" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($p['imagen']) ?>" data-id='imagen_3' alt="<?php echo $p['Nombre']; ?>">
```

Comment: ahora me sale el data-id completo pero el problema que me sale el mismo data-id siempre, incluso pulsando en uno diferente

Comment: Tal vez, te sirva de esta manera, en tal caso tal vez podrías decirme para que intentas recuperar el dato y podemos manejarlo a partir de eso.

Comment: Intento recoger todos los valores de ese registro para mostrarlos a través de un modal, por eso necesito coger distintos id, por que los demás datos me lo coge sin problema pero ese no